# Candle problem about burn rates

Tags: contest-math

19. Two candles, one of which is two centimeters longer than the other, are lit. The
    longer and thinner one is lit at noon and the shorter but fatter one is lit 15 minutes
    later. Each candle burns at a steady rate, and by 4 PM both are the same length. The
    thinner one burns out at 8 PM and the fatter one burns out one hour later. Let x and
    y be the lengths of the two candles. Find x + y.

(A) 15 (B) 30 (C) 40 (D) 45 (E) 50

I tried setting up equations using the length, width, and burn rate of the candles, but it seems too complicated. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 4pm the candles are the same length:

Lets say $z =$ height at 4:00

At 8 pm the faster burning candle burns out at 9 pm the slower burning candle burns out.

The fast candle burns $\frac {z}{4}$ inches per hour.
The slow candle burns $\frac {z}{5}$ inches per hour.

The faster burning candle burns for 8 hours total, the slow candle burns for 8:45 = $\frac {35}{4}$ hours

$x = 8\frac {z}{4} = 2z\\
y = \frac {35}{4} \frac {z}{5} = \frac {7}{4} z\\
x - y = \frac 14 z = 2\\
z = 8\\
x = 16\\
y = 14\\
x + y = 16 + 14 = 30$

Comment: It would be good to define $x$ as the length of the longer candle and $y$ as the length of the shorter.

Comment: @RossMillikan I thought about that, but then didn't as they seemed to be defined in the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got $30$ as the answer.

*Solution.*
Let the candles be labelled as $A$ and $B$ the height of the shorter candle be $x$. The time for which each candle burns is proportional to its height, so $t\propto h$. For candle $A$,
$$\int_0^4\mathrm{d}t_1=k_1\int_{x+2}^h\mathrm{d}h_1$$
$$\implies k_1 = \frac{4}{h-x-2}.$$
For candle $B$,
$$\int_{0.25}^4\mathrm{d}t_2=k_2\int_x^h\mathrm{d}h_2$$
$$\implies k_2 = \frac{3.75}{h-x}.$$
Again, we have for candle $A$
$$\int_0^8\mathrm{d}t_1=k_1\int_{x+2}^0\mathrm{d}h_1$$
$$\implies 8 = -k_1(x+2)$$
and for candle $B$
$$\int_{0.25}^9\mathrm{d}t_2 = k_2\int_x^0\mathrm{d}h_2$$
$$\implies 8.75 = k_2(-x).$$
Substituting for $k_2$ in the above equation we get
$$8.75 = \frac{3.75}{h-x}(-x)\implies h = \frac{5x}{8.75}$$
and we put this value of $h$ in the first equation to get $k_1 = \frac{4}{\frac{5x}{8.75}-x-2}$. Put this value of $k_1$ in the third equation to solve for $x$:
$$8 = -\left(\frac{4}{\frac{5x}{8.75}-x-2}\right)(x+2)$$
from which we readily obtain $x=14$. Thus $y=16$ and $x+y=30$.